# how can I shorten this piece of code that is very redundant

Tags: python

is it possible to shorten this piece of code to only few lines?

```
   if rulesVersion:
        payload["rulesVersion"] = rulesVersion
    if scriptsVersion:
        payload["scriptsVersion"] = scriptsVersion
    if csq:
        payload["CSQ"] = csq
    if rebootTimes:
        payload["RebootTimes"] = rebootTimes
    if acdcSwitch:
        payload["PowerSource"] = acdcSwitch
    if temperature:
        payload["Temperature"] = temperature
```

Comment: The answer really depends on your general code architecture. Care to share a bit more of it?

Comment: Within this incomplete code snippet, no; or at least it shouldn't be shortened since each `if` references a different variable. You would have to restructure the program so that `rulesVersion`, `scriptsVersion`, `csq` etc. are all parts of a collection data type like a `dict` or `list`

Comment: Please do not vandalize posts.

Answer (score 1):

Making a `dict` directly, then filtering to omit the falsy values is probably the safest/most straightforward solution:

```
payload = {"rulesVersion": rulesVersion,
           "scriptsVersion": scriptsVersion,
           "CSQ": csq,
           "RebootTimes": rebootTimes,
           "PowerSource": acdcSwitch,
           "Temperature": temperature}
payload = {k: v for k, v in payload.items() if v}  # Filter out falsy entries
```

An alternative (that risks mismatching names and values if you're not careful) would be to tuple stuff up and loop over the `zip`-ed pairs in a simple `dict` comprehension:

```
names = ("rulesVersion", "scriptsVersion", "CSQ", "RebootTimes", "PowerSource", "Temperature")
values = (rulesVersion, scriptsVersion, csq, rebootTimes, acdcSwitch, temperature)

payload = {name: val for name, val in zip(names, values) if val}
```

If the `payload` is an already existing, non-empty `dict`, you'd change the final line to something like the following to add the new values rather than rebinding `payload` to a brand new `dict`:

```
payload.update({name: val for name, val in zip(names, values) if val})
# Or genexpr for lower memory overhead, but slightly slower/uglier:
# payload.update((name, val) for name, val in zip(names, values) if val)
```

Similarly, for the "build a `dict` then filter it" case where `payload` already exists, just build and filter a separate `dict` (`additional_payload` or the like), then make the last line:

```
payload.update(additional_payload)
```

Comment: I think it would be better to write the names/values in a dictionary in the first place, otherwise it's much harder to check that the names and values match up properly (e.g. `temperature` appears vertically more below `"PowerSource"` than `"Temperature"`). You can still do a dict comprehension to filter for the truthy values afterwards.

Comment: ShadowRanger   what does k and v stands for payload = {k: v for k, v in payload.items() if v}  # Filter out falsy entries

Comment: @AlexHernandez: `k` and `v` are traditional one-letter placeholders for `key` and `value` when iterating an arbitrary `dict`. Use better names if they apply.

Answer (score 0):

Love this question. I wouldn't be as concerned with the number of lines as the readability of the code. Here's how I would approach the problem:

```
# testing
rulesVersion, scriptsVersion, csq, rebootTimes, acdcSwitch, temperature = 1.0, 1.0, 1, "Test", "Test", 42
payload = {}

### BEGIN CODE BODY

data = {
    "rulesVersion": rulesVersion,
    "scriptsVersion": scriptsVersion,
    "CSQ": csq,
    "RebootTimes": rebootTimes,
    "PowerSource": acdcSwitch,
    "Temperature": temperature
}

for key in data:
    val = data[key]
    if(val): payload[key] = val

### END CODE BODY

# testing
print(payload)
```

This test outputs `{'rulesVersion': 1.0, 'scriptsVersion': 1.0, 'CSQ': 1, 'RebootTimes': 'Test', 'PowerSource': 'Test', 'Temperature': 42}`.